# MPI causes breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mpi

I've made an application that counts number of characters using MS MPI, but it causes 4 breakpoints at:
`MPI_File_get_size`, `MPI_File_set_view`, `MPI_File_read` and again at `MPI_File_get_size(fh, &size)`.
Do you know what may cause them? Full code below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int   numprocs, rank, buffer[100];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_File fh;
    MPI_Offset size;
    int char_number;
    const char plik[10] = "file.txt";

    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, plik, MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
    MPI_File_get_size(fh, &size);

    MPI_File_set_view(fh, rank*(size / numprocs), MPI_CHAR, MPI_CHAR, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);


    MPI_File_read(fh, &buffer[100], 1, MPI_CHAR, &status);

    char_number = MPI_File_get_size(fh, &size);
    MPI_File_close(&fh);


    if (rank == 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numprocs; i++) {

            MPI_Recv(&char_number, i, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        }
    }

    else {

        MPI_Send(&char_number, 0, MPI_INT, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }


    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Got rid of breakpoints, but not receiving any output now:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int   numprocs, rank;
    char buffer[100] = { 0 };

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_File fh;
    MPI_Offset size;
    int char_number;
    const char plik[10] = "file.txt";

    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, plik, MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
    MPI_File_get_size(fh, &size);

    MPI_File_set_view(fh, rank*(size / numprocs), MPI_CHAR, MPI_CHAR, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);


    MPI_File_read(fh, buffer, (size/numprocs), MPI_CHAR, &status);

    char_number = MPI_File_get_size(fh, &size);
    MPI_File_close(&fh);


    if (rank == 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numprocs; i++) {
            MPI_Recv(&char_number, i, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }
        cout << "There is: " << char_number << " characters in file.txt";
    }

    else {

        MPI_Send(&char_number, 0, MPI_INT, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }


    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with breakpoint? Do you mean deadlock?

Comment: @Chiel Visual Studio says "CharCounter.exe has triggered a breakpoint."
Application stops at those points I mentioned in main post. I can continue run of the app in debugger, but it ends with no information returned

Comment: Did you look at the call stack?  Did you look at the state of the variables?  What do they tell you?

Comment: your communication pattern causes a deadlock (not to mention they are kind of useless, since `char_number` is simply overwritten). have a look at the man pages of `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()` to make sure you use them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be your breakpoints are still on the list:

> I deleted a breakpoint, but I continue to hit it when I start
>   debugging again
>
> If you deleted a breakpoint while debugging, in some
>   cases you may hit the breakpoint again the next time you start
>   debugging. To stop hitting this breakpoint, make sure all the
>   instances of the breakpoint are removed from the Breakpoints window.

**Source:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

I remember similar situation in the past with some executables. Removing breakpoint from the source code was not enough.

It also might be that you are trying to access non-existing file.

It also might be that your code is not quite OK.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int   numprocs, rank;

    // buffer will keep input data
    char buffer[100] =  { 0 };

    // initialization of MPI world
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_File fh;
    MPI_Offset size;
    int char_number;

    // name of the file with data
    const char plik[10] = "file.txt";

    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, plik, MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);

    MPI_File_get_size(fh, &size);
    // we have to be careful here
    // in this sample we have strong assumption that size of data
    // divides without the reminder by number of processors!
    MPI_File_set_view(fh, rank*(size / numprocs), MPI_CHAR, MPI_CHAR, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
    MPI_File_read(fh, buffer, (size/numprocs), MPI_CHAR, &status);

    char_number = MPI_File_get_size(fh, &size);
    MPI_File_close(&fh);

    printf("My rank: %d - my data: %s\n", rank, buffer);

    if (rank == 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i < numprocs; i++) {
            MPI_Recv(&buffer[i*(size / numprocs)], (size/numprocs), MPI_CHAR, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }
        printf("I have collected data: %s\n",buffer);
    }

    else {
        MPI_Send(&buffer[0], rank*(size / numprocs), MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

For input file

```
> cat file.txt
abcdefgh
```

works as expected:

```
> mpirun -np 2 ./simple2
My rank: 0 - my data: abcd
I have collected data: abcdefgh
My rank: 1 - my data: efgh
```

Question is, whether this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I didn't set them, so it's not my. As VS says it's "unexpected breakpoint"

Comment: If you didn't set them, it might be that you get exception while accessing file and it is reported as breakpoint.

Comment: I'm not best with MPI, that's why code might not be perfect.
It was supposed to count them, not display, but still using what you posted here I see things I did wrong and maybe will be able to correct them

Comment: So after changing some parts of the code I stopped getting breakpoints, but I'm also not receiving any output. If you could take a look (I've posted updated code in topic)

Comment: So again I changed couple things in the code, and managed to make it work! Thank you very much for your time, as it helped me a lot @mko

Comment: .oOo. Cool. Have fun with MPI .oOo.